# Is possible to install many apk from google play and configure android settings

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

We have this requirement to install for many tablets and he asked me that is possible to create some "script" to preinstall about 15 application on device from google play (because he want prepare device from salers). Also i have question about automatically configure device, example add google account, turn on location, add some shortcut to home screen. If is possible please give some suggestion how. I know that is `adb install-multiple` but this install apk from you destination not from google play. Second if I downloaded apk from google play and install using this command, they can update automatically like install "normally" ?

Comment: Yes, the apps you'll download and install from the internet will update as normal apps. And also, You can use some GUI based software for batch install like MobileGO or the best you can create a CMD script for ADB with much delay for every app to be installed. You need not to worry about updates.

Comment: Can install app from directly from google market with `install-multiple` ?

Comment: Nope, you can't do that. What you can do is download all the required APKs and install them with some sort of batch install software. If the devices you are using are rooted then you can use ES file explorer for batch install. It will work without root but then it'll only open the app for install and you have to do everything. What's best is to connect to a laptop and do your job using ADB as that'll be the most efficient way to do what you want to do. That's why I told you to use MobileGO as it is a GUI based software works on ADB.

Comment: What about add google account from adb or other method is possible without root ?

Comment: You have to do this manually and that's gonna be pretty time wasting for too many devices but this is your job.